# Diff algorithms

Tags: xml, algorithm, tree, line, diff

Can somebody recommend some papers (literature) or code snippets about tree-based diff algorithms for XML (based on the DOM-tree)

Thank you very much.

Comment: If this question has been answered, please mark the answer has accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one useful paper on the same : http://pdf.aminer.org/000/301/327/x_diff_an_effective_change_detection_algorithm_for_xml_documents.pdf

Here is one tool you can experiment with: http://www.cs.hut.fi/~ctl/3dm/

You may find the Java source for the above tool as well which maybe of great use.